# Web Worker in Safari

Tags: safari, mobile-safari, web-worker, worker, requestanimationframe

I recently use web worker for a PWA and I call to `Self.RequestAnimationFrame()` in my worker.
But problem is just in **Safari browser** it's fire Exception that `RequestAnimationFrame()` does not exist.
The question is :

- Am I calling it wrong ? or
- Is there any other solution for this    situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WorkerScope.requestAnimationFrame` (note the lower-cased `r`) has been added only very recently in the standards, and as of today, only Chrome based browsers do support it.
Note that it has been added so that we can use it with [OffsreenCanvas,](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas) using this method outside of this use has very little sense since your Worker is otherwise disconnected from the monitor.

Given that you didn't tell why you need this method, it's quite hard to find the proper equivalent, but chances are that a simple `setTimeout(fn, 16)` would do, or if it's to respond to some animation that occurs in the main thread, then just respond to `onmessage` events.